# Is there a way to draw an border around an image using ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I'm on windows and need a way to batch process images to add a border around images that are 25px away from the image and follow the edges. Is there any way to do this please? I've attached an example of what I mean.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do that in ImageMagick 6.

Floodfill the background to make it transparent. Extract the alpha channel. Then dilated it and then extract the boundary. Then invert that and multiply it against the original input. Save the result.

Input:

[image]

Unix syntax:

```
convert dragon.png \
\( -clone 0 -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" \
-alpha extract -morphology dilate disk:10 \
-morphology edgein diamond:2 -negate \) \
-compose multiply -composite \
dragon_contour.png
```

Windows syntax:

```
convert dragon.png ^
( -clone 0 -fill none -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" ^
-alpha extract -morphology dilate disk:10 ^
-morphology edgein diamond:2 -negate ) ^
-compose multiply -composite ^
dragon_contour.png
```

If using ImageMagick 7, change `convert` to `magick` and change `matte` to `alpha`

[image]